# iOS5 how to re-use a UIViewController with UINavigationController?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I have a UITabBar and a UINavigationController that hold my view controllers.

The tab bar has a UITableViewController presenting core data rows as one of the tabs. It is always available to the user.

Right now **I need to select one of the same core data rows that that UITableViewController is showing**. What is the best way to go about getting the same data?
 Do I:

1. **Create a brand new** UITableViewController, put in the code to select a core data object and return that object when the controller is presented and dismissed
2. Try to **re-use** the existing controller that is assigned to a UITabBar, can I push it on another UINavigationController or present it modally?
3. Try to **create another instance** of the same view controller, push/present it modally and then get rid of it?

Right now I'm leaning towards option 3.

Answer (score 0):

This is what apple has to [say](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW18) in regard to presenting views modally.

> A modal view (that is, a view presented modally) provides
>   self-contained functionality in the context of the current task or
>   workflow.
>
> Appearance and Behavior
>
> A modal view occupies the entire application screen, which strengthens
>   the user’s perception of entering a separate, transient mode in which
>   they can accomplish something. On iPad, a modal view might also occupy
>   the entire area of a parent view, such as a popover.
>
> A modal view can display text if appropriate, and contains the
>   controls necessary to perform the task. A modal view generally
>   displays a button that completes the task and dismisses the view, and
>   a Cancel button users can tap to abandon the task.

I would only lean to present a view modally if you think this fits the user needs.

Comment: I'm trying to let the user plot a set of data. One of my controllers already holds a list of available data. I think it's perfectly fine to display a modal controller in this case